# Why isn't feedly updating content from my RSS feed?

Tags: rss, feedly

So for some strange reason, the feedly feed for https://www.quora.com/Alex-K-Chen/rss hasn't updated for 30 days, and I'm not sure why. The regular rss feed URL is still being updated at regular intervals.